# PHP convert html width height attribute to inline style

Tags: php

**How do i go from this**

```
width="200" height="300"
```

**to this with php**

```
width:200px; height:300px;
```

Basically i want to remove the quotes and equal signs and insert a semi colon after each attribute

Comment: Presumably moving from html attributes to an in-line style attribute?

Comment: @cillosis getimagesize(x) gives an html width and height attr. I want to convert that to inline css

Comment: If it's not some special case, don't replace it for images. It would make sense the other way around (from inline style to `width` and `height` attributes). See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247685/should-i-specify-height-and-width-attributes-for-my-imgs-in-html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use regexp:

```
<?php
  $html = 'width="200" height="300"';
  $pattern = '/width="(\d+)"\s+height="(\d+)"/';
  preg_match($pattern, $html, $matches);
  $style = "width:".$matches[1]."px; height:".$matches[2]."px;";
  echo $style;
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `str_replace` or a regular expression.

As concrete example:

```
 $string = 'width="200" height="300"'
 $string = str_replace('="', ':', $string);
 $string = str_replace('"', 'px;', $string);
```

But beware, if there are also other attributes or s.th. else - regular expressions could be the better way.

Comment: html attribute does not contain px. It looks like `width="200" height="300"`

Comment: You are right but I copied the string from initial query, it must have been changed afterwards, I will adjust my answer.

Comment: @DavidThomas yes, it replaces each occurence of "= with :

Comment: Oh, I see - you are right - my mistake. It should read =" - I will update it.

Comment: @fkerber thanks this works, although i think paker has a more bullet proof solution. Different browsers may add additional spaces between attributes or use ' instead of ".

Answer (score 0):

Just don't use that output format of `getimagesize()` if you're not going to include it directly.

Use first two values:

```
list($width, $height) = getimagesize("img/flag.jpg");
echo 'width:'.$width.'px; height:'.$height.'px;';
```