# Image not showing only in IE9

Tags: css, internet-explorer, joomla, internet-explorer-9

The site is www.bhct.bm

The image on the main page doesn't come up for some reason in IE9. Looks fine in other browsers.

Unable to tell what the problem is...

Here is what I'm seeing - [image: Screenshot]

Comment: Try specifying a width for that image, it's getting set to 1px wide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `width="auto"` attribute on `img` tag then its looking fine.

UPDATE : Look Gumbo's comment below.

Comment: so you're right - now I just need to figure out how that's being added, considering it's a generated page.

Comment: It would be better to specify the actual width. Increases load time: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247685/should-i-specify-height-and-width-attributes-for-my-imgs-in-html

Answer (score 0):

Add `width="960px"` to your img. Right now it is set to `width="auto"`.

Comment: Probably you don't need "px" inside "width="

Comment: Right... good catch. Was originally writing it for the css :-/

Answer (score 0):

specify the image width as `width=955px`, it is set to auto because it does not seem you specify any width within the tag or external style sheet. `width:auto` is default