# How to define dynamic height in css (or html)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

For example, I have an image of 100x100, and want to show it in DIVs of 100x100, 80x80, 50x50, 20x20.

so I have to define something like this in css

```
.div_100 {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  // other 
}

.div_80 {
  height: 80px;
  width: 80px;
  // other same 
}

.div_50 {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  // other same 
}

.div_20 {
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  // other same 
}
```

Is this normal? Is there any more elegant way to do this?

Or make the css simple?

Comment: You want the `div`s to show at one time on your page, or you want them to scale with screen size?

Comment: maybe one div on one page, or two divs on one page. dont scale

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? http://jsfiddle.net/0q527ush/ ..

Comment: Yes, exactly what i want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to display an image at different sizes on your web page, your code is on the right path.

http://jsfiddle.net/0q527ush/

HTML

```
<div class="div_100">IMAGE</div>
<div class="div_80">IMAGE</div>
<div class="div_50">IMAGE</div>
<div class="div_20"></div>
```

CSS

```
div {
    border: 2px dashed black;
    margin: 10px;
    background-color: #ccc;
    text-align: center;
}

.div_100 {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}

.div_80 {
  height: 80px;
  width: 80px; 
}

.div_50 {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
    font-size: .8em;
}

.div_20 {
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
}
```

**NOTE:** Don't forget to [define the correct `width` and `height` in each `<img>` tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247685/should-i-specify-height-and-width-attributes-for-my-imgs-in-html).