# Enlarge images in my html page using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I try to enlarge images  in my html page by using JavaScript.
The image in the html- source code always has the height/width 100 Pixel.  By clicking on the image, the image should be displayed in original size.
By clicking the image again, the image should displayed in height/width 100 Pixel.

Example image in the html source code:

```
<img src="image.jpg" onClick="swap(this)" onmouseover="" style="cursor: pointer;" height="100" width="100">
```

My JavaScript source code:

```
function swap(img)
 {
  if (img.width==="100")
   {
    img.width="auto";
    img.height="100%";
   }
  else
   {
    img.width="100";
    img.height="100";
   }
}
```

My Problem is the image size dose not change. What am I doing wrong?
Does anyone have maybe a better idea?

Comment: `===(strict comparison)` will not make it `true` as `img.width` will be of type `Number`

Comment: Play with the `style-properties` than `Element-properties`

Comment: Haven't done it in a while but i think you should use img.clientWidth, this returns the width as it is rendered in the browser.

Comment: Why not using JS only for toggling class and leave the rest of the job to CSS?

Comment: Are you looking for a pure-javascript solution or you are using any javascript framework/library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provided your images don't already have a CSS class, you can swap a full-size class easily.

```js
function swap(img) {
  if (img.className !== "full-size") img.className = "full-size";
  else img.className = "";
}
```

```css
.full-size {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://multimedia.journalism.berkeley.edu/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/css101-main.jpg" onClick="swap(this)" onmouseover="" style="cursor: pointer;" height="100" width="100">
```

You'd be better off using `jQuery` to handle multiple classes on a single HTML element though.

Comment: Thanks to all of you for helping.

Answer (score 1):

Using image.width is not the best practice, and it has been so for a very long time.

What you should be doing is using the "style" property, both in your HTML and in the JavaScript. Aside from that, you always need to define units, e.g. pixels (px), percent (%).

So your image should look something like this (I ignored the events):

```
<img style="cursor: pointer; width: 100%, height: 100%;">
```

I didn't understand if you wanted 100px or 100%, so change as needed.

Your JS should look something like this:

```
function swap(img)
 {
  if (img.style.width==="100%")
   {
    img.style.width="auto";
    img.style.height="100%";
   }
  else
   {
    img.style.width="100%";
    img.style.height="100%";
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Your actual code:**

In your code the problem was, as stated in comments, the strict comparaison where you were comparing a `string` with a `number`, because `img.width` is a `number` and `"100"` is a `string`.

So to fix it you just need to change the comparaison, either byu using `==` comparaison or just `100` instead of `"100"`:

```js
function swap(img) {
  if (img.width === 100) {
    img.width = "auto";
    img.height = "100%";
  } else {
    img.width = "100";
    img.height = "100";
  }
}
```

```html
<img src="image.jpg" onClick="swap(this)" onmouseover="" style="cursor: pointer;" height="100" width="100">
```

**Alternatives:**

- In fact in Javascript to access an element attribute (width or
  height) you better use **[`element.getAttribute()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute)**, this
  is how should be your code:

```js
function swap(img) {
  if (img.getAttribute("width") === "100") {
    img.width = "auto";
    img.height = "100%";
  } else {
    img.width = "100";
    img.height = "100";
  }
}
```

```html
<img src="image.jpg" onclick="swap(this)" onmouseover="" style="cursor: pointer;" height="100" width="100">
```

- Otherwise, just use `height` and `width` as properties in the style of your
  element, then access it using `element.style.height`.

**Further reading:**

For further reading you can see the diffirence between `height`/`width` element attributes and styles properties, here:

[Should I specify height and width attributes for my IMGs in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247685/should-i-specify-height-and-width-attributes-for-my-imgs-in-html)

Answer (score 1):

Use `style` property of the element to apply `style`. Use `.width` property just for conditions.

```js
function swap(img) {
  if (img.width === 100) {
    //Remove the quotes around `100` as you are using strict comparison
    img.width = "auto";
    img.style.width = "auto";
    img.style.height = "100%";
  } else {
    img.width = "100";
    img.style.width = "";
    img.style.height = "";
  }
}
```

```html
<img src="http://www.mariodemiranda.com/uploads/showcase/4_pic_indian-art-4.jpg" onClick="swap(this)" onmouseover="" style="cursor: pointer;" height="100" width="100">
```

**Edit:** Using css `class`, `.contains`,`.add`/`.remove` will be handy.

```js
function swap(img) {
  img.classList.contains('fs') ? img.classList.remove('fs') : img.classList.add('fs')
}
```

```css
.fs {
  width: auto;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://www.mariodemiranda.com/uploads/showcase/4_pic_indian-art-4.jpg" onClick="swap(this)" onmouseover="" style="cursor: pointer;" height="100" width="100">
```

Answer (score 1):

[Fiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/jfpfzgps/1/)

```
<img src="https://c7.staticflickr.com/3/2538/3742771246_2648fa4e6e_b.jpg" onClick="swap(this)" onmouseover="" style="cursor: pointer;" height="100" width="100">
 <script>
   function swap(img)
    {
 debugger;
 if (img.width===100)
{
 img.style.height = 'auto';
 img.style.width = 'auto';
 }
else
{
   img.style.height = '100px';
img.style.width = '100px';
}
}</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer using css to do this and changing the element class accordingly when click occurs.

The script:

```
function swap(img) {
  if (img.classList.contains('fullsize')) {
    img.classList.remove('fullsize');
  } else {
    img.classList.add('fullsize');
  }
}
```

The element:

```
<img src="image.jpg" onclick="swap(this)" class="resize-image" style="cursor: pointer;">
```

CSS:

```
.resize-image {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.resize-image.fullsize {
  width: auto;
  height: 100%;
}

// Or if using SASS etc

.resize-image {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;

  &.fullsize {
    width: auto;
    height: 100%;
  }
}
```

Comment: this the first rational approach among other answers)

Comment: `Controller`..`View`..`Angular`.. Why ?

Comment: @Rayon I'm sorry, what?

Comment: @thepio, Angular is neither tagged in the question nor mentioned in the question.. Why does this answer based on `angular` ?

Comment: Oh god, you are correct. Somehow I ended up here even though I was going through angularjs related questions only. In this case your answer is the correct one, even though it would be still better to manipulate a css class in my opinion.

Comment: I added a non AngularJS way to do this. Once again I apologize for my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

```
function swap(img)
 {
 debugger
  if (img.style.width==="100px")
   {
    img.style.width="auto";
    img.style.height="100%";
   }
  else
   {
    img.style.width="100px";
    img.style.height="100px";
   }
}
```