# Javascript Image OnLoad event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know I can attach an event listener to a loading image so that it'll trigger when the image finishes loading like this:

```
<img id="mine" src="image.jpg" />

<script>
$('#mine').load(function() {
  console.log($(this).height()); //The image's height
  console.log($(this).width()); //The image's width
})
</script>
```

But my browser knows how big the image is going to be as soon as the header is loaded - can I tap into that event, so that as soon as the browser knows the image's size I can resize elements on my page?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't. But, you should pass the image's dimensions along with the tag.

```
<img id="mine" src="image.jpg" width="100" height="100">
```

For example, in PHP you can use the [`getimagesize()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php) function.

It's even [a recommended practice](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/best-practices/rendering#SpecifyImageDimensions) to improve browser rendering.

Comment: Shouldn't the `width` and `height` be in a `style` attribute?

Comment: The `height` and `width` attributes may "seem" deprecated, but they are more than acceptable. See also [Image width/height as an attribute or in CSS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/640190/image-width-height-as-an-attribute-or-in-css)

Comment: Thanks Alexander and Boaz! I knew that those attributes existed, but I thought they were deprecated from the W3C Specifications.