# Image overflows on iOS safari

Tags: css

I have the following HTML

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<body style="
    box-sizing: border-box;
    max-width: 100vw;
">
    <main style="width: 60%; margin: 0 auto;">
        <h1>Title</h1>
        <img style="width: 100%; height: auto;"
             src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1513622790541-eaa84d356909?q=40&w=1974&auto=format&fit=crop"
             width="1974" height="1481" alt="">
    </main>
    <span>Something else</span>
</body>

</html>
```

- The width of `body` is locked to being `100` viewport unit
- I have a inner block that should be 60% of the width of the parent's width
- Inside is a image that I want to take up 100% of it's parent width (with an automatic height to retain aspect ratio)

This works on desktop

[image]

but on iOS don't get the same behaviour. The image spills off the page and adds a scrollbar?

[image]

Why is it not respecting the widths? How do I get it working?

Comment: Remove the width and height attributes from the `img` tag.

Comment: Please make the code into a snippet so we can see the problem on IOS easily.

Comment: The code works fine for me on IOS. What version are you using?

Comment: @psdpainter - I'm not sure why that would make a difference - the html width attribute shd. get superceded by the CSS in the style attribute, see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20742675/whats-the-difference-between-htmls-and-csss-width-attribute

Comment: @AHaworth I tested it on iOS 15.6. I got the error looking at https://kaleidawave.github.io/posts/cool-things-23/, are the images large or inline with the rest of content on there? It's hard to debug what is going on mobile

Comment: I've tried your link on an iPhone SE (IOS 16.6) and an iPad (IOS 16.7.2) and both of them are centering everything OK on that page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just set `max-width: 100vw` on to the images themselves. Seems like it was fixed  in more recent versions of Safari

Answer (score -1):

Do you have one of these involved? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Viewport_meta_tag

If you don't tell the browser specifically to treat your web page as a responsive layout, it'll zoom out to account for the content/space. This could be the source of your problem.

(you should also probably set your img element to display: block)