# How to make a fixed column in CSS using CSS Grid Layout?

Tags: html, css, grid-layout, css-grid

I've made a simple site with a `#container` div that is parent to two divs: `#left` and `#right`, by using [Grid Layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout):

Is there any way to make the left column fixed? I'd like the left text to persist on its position, and the right text to be scrollable as it is now. Adding `position: fixed` to `#left` breaks the layout.

I'm aware that this question has been already solved, but I'd appreciate a way to make it work with the grid layout.

Thanks.

```css
body {
  margin: 0 0 0 0;
}

#container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 50% 50%;
}

.section {
  padding: 5% 5% 5% 5%;
}

#left {
  background-color: aquamarine;
}

#right {
  background-color: beige;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="left" class="section">
    <p>This should not scroll</p>
  </div>
  <div id="right" class="section">
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla aliquet consectetur purus nec volutpat. Donec vel libero nec est commodo facilisis vel et nisl. Praesent porta sed eros eu porta. Cras dolor nulla, ullamcorper et tincidunt quis, porta ut
      tellus. Maecenas cursus libero sed accumsan luctus. Integer sed consequat ante. Morbi sit amet lectus tempor elit tempor cursus ut sed enim. Donec placerat bibendum volutpat.
    </p>
    <p>
      Nunc sit amet eleifend sapien, sed tincidunt neque. Donec id sapien et nunc scelerisque iaculis dignissim nec mauris. Fusce at pretium nulla. Maecenas vel rutrum tellus, a viverra nunc. Aenean at arcu vitae dui faucibus dapibus. Vivamus hendrerit blandit
      mollis. Aenean sit amet lectus a metus faucibus condimentum. Proin vel eros ut elit pharetra lacinia vitae eu orci. Etiam massa massa, aliquam at pulvinar ut, porttitor eu mauris. Ut in iaculis sapien.
    </p>
    <p>
      In vitae rhoncus arcu. Maecenas elementum nunc quis magna finibus, vitae imperdiet diam pulvinar. Phasellus sit amet nibh eu massa facilisis luctus. Nulla ullamcorper sodales ante id vestibulum. Fusce felis nisi, lacinia sit amet mauris vel, euismod suscipit
      neque. Mauris quis libero eget enim facilisis pharetra. Fusce non ligula auctor nunc pretium dignissim eget eget turpis. Nam ultricies dolor ac libero maximus vestibulum. Mauris et tortor vitae nisi ultrices vestibulum ac id mauris. Proin interdum
      dapibus sollicitudin. Phasellus ultricies vulputate sem id hendrerit. Cras eget posuere nunc, in placerat velit. Pellentesque sed ante at elit ornare efficitur. Donec sed condimentum nisl. Curabitur dapibus leo id ligula dignissim pharetra.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

*You wrote:*

> Is there any way to make the left column fixed?
>
> I'd appreciate a way to make it work with the grid layout.

If you want the element to remain a grid item, then the answer is "no".

Once an element has `position: absolute` or `position: fixed` ([which is a form of absolute positioning, with reference to the viewport](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visuren.html#choose-position)), it takes on new characteristics:

- the element is removed from the document flow
- the element is removed from the [**grid formatting context**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#grid-model)
- the element is no longer a grid item

*From the spec:*

> [**10. Absolute
>   Positioning**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#static-position)
>
> An absolutely-positioned child of a grid container is out-of-flow and
>   not a grid item, and so does not affect the placement of other items
>   or the sizing of the grid.

So a *grid item* doesn't work well with absolute positioning.

However, you won't have a problem applying `position: fixed` to a *grid container*.

Consider managing your `#left` and `#right` elements separately. `#left` can be a fixed-position grid container. `#right` can be another grid container and remain in-flow.

---

Also, as an aside, you've given your grid items percentage-based padding:

```
.section {
    padding: 5% 5% 5% 5%;
}
```

When applying `margin` and `padding` to grid items (and flex items), it's best to stay away from percentage units. Browsers may compute the values differently.

- [Percentage padding on grid item being ignored in Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42708323/3597276)
- [Why doesn't percentage padding work on flex items in Firefox?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36783190/3597276)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm marking this as accepted because it is more correct than the previous.

Comment: "Once an element has position: absolute or position: fixed" does the same applies to position: sticky?

Comment: `position: sticky` is a hybrid of *relative* and *fixed* positioning. You'll have to test that with grid layout across browsers, especially since `position: sticky` has only [partial support](https://caniuse.com/#search=sticky) in most major browsers.  @MiguelPynto

Answer (score 67):

You can achieve this by adding these CSS rules to your id #left:

```
position: sticky; // See link
top: 0; //to make it stick to the top of the screen
height: 100vh; // make the height equal to 100 view height
```

Link for sticky position: [Sticky position with nothing but CSS](https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/sticky-positioning-with-nothing-but-css--cms-24042)

> sticky is a new value for the position property, added as part of CSS3 Layout Module Spec. It acts similarly to relative positioning, in that it doesn’t remove anything from the document flow. In other words, a sticky element has no effect on the position of adjacent elements and doesn't collapse its parent element.

Hope it helps you

**EDIT (fix jumpy behaviour)**

In order to avoid the left part to jump up at the end of the page, just add the following CSS rule to your id #left:

```
box-sizing: border-box;
```

See updated code snippet:

```css
body {
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
}

#container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 50% 50%;
}

.section {
    padding: 5% 5% 5% 5%;
}

#left {
    background-color: aquamarine;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    height: 100vh;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

#right {
    background-color: beige;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div id="left" class="section">
        <p>This should not scroll</p>
    </div>
    <div id="right" class="section">
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla aliquet consectetur purus nec volutpat. Donec vel libero nec est commodo facilisis vel et nisl. Praesent porta sed eros eu porta. Cras dolor nulla, ullamcorper et tincidunt quis, porta ut tellus. Maecenas cursus libero sed accumsan luctus. Integer sed consequat ante. Morbi sit amet lectus tempor elit tempor cursus ut sed enim. Donec placerat bibendum volutpat.
        </p>
        <p>
            Nunc sit amet eleifend sapien, sed tincidunt neque. Donec id sapien et nunc scelerisque iaculis dignissim nec mauris. Fusce at pretium nulla. Maecenas vel rutrum tellus, a viverra nunc. Aenean at arcu vitae dui faucibus dapibus. Vivamus hendrerit blandit mollis. Aenean sit amet lectus a metus faucibus condimentum. Proin vel eros ut elit pharetra lacinia vitae eu orci. Etiam massa massa, aliquam at pulvinar ut, porttitor eu mauris. Ut in iaculis sapien.
        </p>
        <p>
            In vitae rhoncus arcu. Maecenas elementum nunc quis magna finibus, vitae imperdiet diam pulvinar. Phasellus sit amet nibh eu massa facilisis luctus. Nulla ullamcorper sodales ante id vestibulum. Fusce felis nisi, lacinia sit amet mauris vel, euismod suscipit neque. Mauris quis libero eget enim facilisis pharetra. Fusce non ligula auctor nunc pretium dignissim eget eget turpis. Nam ultricies dolor ac libero maximus vestibulum. Mauris et tortor vitae nisi ultrices vestibulum ac id mauris. Proin interdum dapibus sollicitudin. Phasellus ultricies vulputate sem id hendrerit. Cras eget posuere nunc, in placerat velit. Pellentesque sed ante at elit ornare efficitur. Donec sed condimentum nisl. Curabitur dapibus leo id ligula dignissim pharetra.
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! This works almost perfectly, however, when you reach the end of the page, the "This should not scroll" text scrolls a little bit up. Do you know what could be causing that?

Comment: Sorry for the late response, but that is caused by the fact that your have a padding declared on your '.section'. The CSS rule 'height: 100vh;' takes the height of the screen **+ any other dimensions (like padding and margin)**, so that's the reason why it is jumpy. If you want, I could look for the solution for your case?

Comment: I added ` box-sizing: border-box;` but it did not fix the end of page problem.

Comment: This is such a `#BADA55` trick! thanks for this

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
body {
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
}

#container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 50% 50%;
}

.section {
    padding: 5% 5% 5% 5%;
}

#left {
    background-color: aquamarine;

    p {
      position: fixed;
    }
}

#right {
    background-color: beige;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/km5gdrcm/3/

Comment: Thanks for your answer! This did work. However, you linked to the wrong fiddle. [This one should work](https://jsfiddle.net/km5gdrcm/4/).

Comment: This doesn't work. The question was: *I'd appreciate a way to make it work with the grid layout.* This simply takes the `p` out of the document flow and fixes it relative to the viewport. That's standard positioning. The fact is, fixed positioning and grid items don't work well together.

Answer (score 1):

You can't make left be sticky, but you can make all content in it be sticky. For this you should make sticky wrapper element and place all content in it like so:

HTML:

```
<div class="grid">

    <div class="left">
       <div class="sticky_wrapper">Content</div>
    </div>

    <div class="right">
        Content
    </div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
.grid { display: grid; grid-template-columns: 50% 50%; }
.left { background-color: aquamarine; }
.right { background-color: beige; }
.sticky_wrapper { position: sticky; top: 0; }
```

So all content in the sticky wrapper will not scrool.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/lycrest15/4es7x3f9/)

here is the code

```
body {
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
}

#container {
    display: grid;

}

.section {
    padding: 5% 5% 5% 5%;
}

#left {
    background-color: aquamarine;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    width: 50%
}

#right {
    background-color: beige;
    overflow: scroll;
    width: 50%;
    right: 0;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! However, this doesn't look right, at least on my browser. [Here's a screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/4GULHGJ.png). Besides, I believe that removing the `grid-template-columns` instruction defeats the purpose of the grid layout.

Comment: For me, adding `left: 0;` to the column with the `position: sticky;` property was the key to making it work properly.  (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VVHvSTWcK-M)  However, it's a bit transparent, which seems to be a webkit bug (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47923240/opacity-issue-in-sticky-table-header-structure).

Answer (score 0):

Add one more div in right panel which panel you want to scroll for that give some `max-height` and `overflow: auto;` so left panel will be stick and right panel content will scroll.

```css
body {
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
}

#container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 50% 50%;
}

.section {
    padding: 5% 5% 5% 5%;
}

#left {
    background-color: aquamarine;
}

#right {
    background-color: beige;
}
.scroll-div {
    max-height: 300px;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div id="left" class="section">
        <p>This should not scroll</p>
    </div>
    <div id="right" class="section">
        <div class="scroll-div">
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla aliquet consectetur purus nec volutpat. Donec vel libero nec est commodo facilisis vel et nisl. Praesent porta sed eros eu porta. Cras dolor nulla, ullamcorper et tincidunt quis, porta ut tellus. Maecenas cursus libero sed accumsan luctus. Integer sed consequat ante. Morbi sit amet lectus tempor elit tempor cursus ut sed enim. Donec placerat bibendum volutpat.
        </p>
        <p>
            Nunc sit amet eleifend sapien, sed tincidunt neque. Donec id sapien et nunc scelerisque iaculis dignissim nec mauris. Fusce at pretium nulla. Maecenas vel rutrum tellus, a viverra nunc. Aenean at arcu vitae dui faucibus dapibus. Vivamus hendrerit blandit mollis. Aenean sit amet lectus a metus faucibus condimentum. Proin vel eros ut elit pharetra lacinia vitae eu orci. Etiam massa massa, aliquam at pulvinar ut, porttitor eu mauris. Ut in iaculis sapien.
        </p>
        <p>
            In vitae rhoncus arcu. Maecenas elementum nunc quis magna finibus, vitae imperdiet diam pulvinar. Phasellus sit amet nibh eu massa facilisis luctus. Nulla ullamcorper sodales ante id vestibulum. Fusce felis nisi, lacinia sit amet mauris vel, euismod suscipit neque. Mauris quis libero eget enim facilisis pharetra. Fusce non ligula auctor nunc pretium dignissim eget eget turpis. Nam ultricies dolor ac libero maximus vestibulum. Mauris et tortor vitae nisi ultrices vestibulum ac id mauris. Proin interdum dapibus sollicitudin. Phasellus ultricies vulputate sem id hendrerit. Cras eget posuere nunc, in placerat velit. Pellentesque sed ante at elit ornare efficitur. Donec sed condimentum nisl. Curabitur dapibus leo id ligula dignissim pharetra.
        </p>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! However, that's not what I wanted. I'd want the main scroll bar to scroll the contents on the right, not the right section to have an additional scroll bar.

Answer (score 0):

I had a bit of the same problem. I needed a fixed sidenav (col 1) with scrollable content (col 2). Here's how I solved the problem (note that I use styled-component, but you can surely do it with regular css, sass, less, or whatever):

```
<Grid>
  <SideNav>
    <Sider>
  </SideNav>
  <Content />
<Grid>
```

Now the css property for each of those styled-components:

```
const Grid = styled.div`
  position: relative;
  display: grid;
  height: 100%;
  grid-template-columns: auto 1fr;
  grid-template-areas: 'sidenav content';
`

const Sidenav = styled.div`
  position: relative;
  grid-area: sidenav;
`
const Content = styled.div`
  position: relative;
  grid-area: content;
  width: 100%;
`

const Sider = styled.aside`
  position: fixed;
  height: 100vh;
`
```

It looks like this, but a bit more complex on my side since I also have a header and footer in my grid, and the sidenav is collapsable. But I think this could work for you.

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon this today and got it working by adding:

```
#left {
  position: sticky;
  left: 0;
}
```