# Opacity issue in sticky table header structure

Tags: css, z-index, opacity

I have created fiddle for reference :- [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/orbs4g07/5/).
In this i have table structure and i want stick the table header on top of page, so for that i have used `translateY()` you can check it on **FIDDLE**.
Now on first column there is checkbox with **opacity: 0.3**.

Now when i scroll the table and any check box of **tbody** is overlapped with checkbox of **thead** then i am not able to check the thead checkbox.

I have also created video of problem :- [VIDEO](https://drive.google.com/file/d/143dfHv1ji5o89xKq6aGNyrvaoq4qeBFN/view). if there's **opacity** less then one and then if you try and overlap the checkboxes, then the thead checkbox won't be selected. If i use **opacity:1** it is working fine. Even if i give the **z-index** to header's check box it is not working. **NOTE :-** I cant remove or change the input opacity

Comment: which browser ? on Chrome it's fine for me

Comment: Why are you giving the opacity in the first place?

Comment: @TemaniAfif It doesn't work. What he is trying to say is, if there's opacity and then if you try and overlap the checkboxes, then the thead checkbox won't be selected.

Comment: Yes correct @Highdef, i have tested it in chrome.

Comment: @Highdef and i tested and it's working for me :) i can select/deselect everything

Comment: Running Chrome 63 and can confirm I have the same issue as OP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Weird bug. It seems to be be solved by placing `<thead>` below `<tbody>` in the html source. 
https://jsfiddle.net/euejc4kg/

So it has to do with stacking/order, I figured I might fix it by setting translate3d or anything on the tbody as well but that didn't seem to fix it. But maybe that's something someone else can work with.

Another option might be to use labels on top of the checkboxes and not have pointer events on the checkboxes at all.

Comment: Nice find! I tried playing with the stacking in CSS, and translate3d etc... nothing worked. +1

Comment: Ya this works for me. But what if we don't want to edit or add in html is there any way only with CSS. (Ya it's weird but just want know if there is any way)
Thank you..

Comment: Haven't found that yet(don't have much time right now), but if it's only not the html you want to change you can move it with JavaScript. Only being able to change it with CSS seems like an odd requirement and might need too many bad hacks that only make it worse in the long run.

Comment: @sol and "René" If you find any alternative please do let me know it would be very helpful using only CSS... 
Thank you..

Answer (score 1):

Here's a (hacky) workaround for Chrome...

Create the opacity effect using a `psuedoelement` on top of the `inputs` and set `pointer-events: none`.

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sol_b/8r7yLook/1/)

```js
$(this).on('scroll', function() {
  $('table').find('#table_header').css('transform', 'translateY(' + $(this).scrollTop() + 'px)');
});
```

```css
table {
  position: relative;
}

table:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  
  display: block;
  background: #fff;
  opacity: .7;
  width: 20px;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead id='table_header'>
    <tr>
      <th>
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox" name="">
        </div>
      </th>
      <th>a</th>
      <th>b</th>
      <th>c</th>
      <th>d</th>
      <th>e</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox" name="">
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>a1</td>
      <td>b1</td>
      <td>c1</td>
      <td>d1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox" name="">
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>a1</td>
      <td>b1</td>
      <td>c1</td>
      <td>d1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox" name="">
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>a1</td>
      <td>b1</td>
      <td>c1</td>
      <td>d1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox" name="">
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>a1</td>
      <td>b1</td>
      <td>c1</td>
      <td>d1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox" name="">
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>a1</td>
      <td>b1</td>
      <td>c1</td>
      <td>d1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox" name="">
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>a1</td>
      <td>b1</td>
      <td>c1</td>
      <td>d1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox" name="">
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>a1</td>
      <td>b1</td>
      <td>c1</td>
      <td>d1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox" name="">
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>a1</td>
      <td>b1</td>
      <td>c1</td>
      <td>d1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox" name="">
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>a1</td>
      <td>b1</td>
      <td>c1</td>
      <td>d1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox" name="">
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>a1</td>
      <td>b1</td>
      <td>c1</td>
      <td>d1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox" name="">
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>a1</td>
      <td>b1</td>
      <td>c1</td>
      <td>d1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox" name="">
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>a1</td>
      <td>b1</td>
      <td>c1</td>
      <td>d1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox" name="">
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>a1</td>
      <td>b1</td>
      <td>c1</td>
      <td>d1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox" name="">
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>a1</td>
      <td>b1</td>
      <td>c1</td>
      <td>d1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox" name="">
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>a1</td>
      <td>b1</td>
      <td>c1</td>
      <td>d1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox" name="">
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>a1</td>
      <td>b1</td>
      <td>c1</td>
      <td>d1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox" name="">
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>a1</td>
      <td>b1</td>
      <td>c1</td>
      <td>d1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox" name="">
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>a1</td>
      <td>b1</td>
      <td>c1</td>
      <td>d1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox" name="">
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>a1</td>
      <td>b1</td>
      <td>c1</td>
      <td>d1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox" name="">
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>a1</td>
      <td>b1</td>
      <td>c1</td>
      <td>d1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox" name="">
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>a1</td>
      <td>b1</td>
      <td>c1</td>
      <td>d1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox" name="">
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>a1</td>
      <td>b1</td>
      <td>c1</td>
      <td>d1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox" name="">
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>a1</td>
      <td>b1</td>
      <td>c1</td>
      <td>d1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox" name="">
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>a1</td>
      <td>b1</td>
      <td>c1</td>
      <td>d1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox" name="">
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>a1</td>
      <td>b1</td>
      <td>c1</td>
      <td>d1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox" name="">
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>a1</td>
      <td>b1</td>
      <td>c1</td>
      <td>d1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox" name="">
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>a1</td>
      <td>b1</td>
      <td>c1</td>
      <td>d1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox" name="">
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>a1</td>
      <td>b1</td>
      <td>c1</td>
      <td>d1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox" name="">
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>a1</td>
      <td>b1</td>
      <td>c1</td>
      <td>d1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox" name="">
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>a1</td>
      <td>b1</td>
      <td>c1</td>
      <td>d1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox" name="">
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>a1</td>
      <td>b1</td>
      <td>c1</td>
      <td>d1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox" name="">
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>a1</td>
      <td>b1</td>
      <td>c1</td>
      <td>d1</td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Here you have removed input's opacity but i can't remove the opacity (Because of weird requirement :( ) FIDDLE :- https://jsfiddle.net/8r7yLook/2/

And if i remove that again it is not working

Comment: I think a combination of a webkit bug and `opacity` is causing the problem. Can you revisit that requirement and see if it can be changed?

Comment: @sol Sorry, i can't do that. Is there any way to do it?

Comment: @VandanShah If I knew another way I'd update my answer, but I can't find one.