# How to set a sticky column with css grids?

Tags: css, grid, css-grid

I'm trying to create a two column layout where the left column is fixed.

In the process this is the first time I'm using css grids

```
.container{
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 38.196601125% auto; /* 61.803398875%*/
}
.main-content{
  padding: 0 100px;
  overflow-y:scroll; 
}
```

The HTML is

```
<div className="container">
  <Sidebar /> // just a div
  <div className='main-content'>
  </div>
</div>
```

The content bellow the fold is hidden and there's no scroll

Comment: Grid is an overkill for this requirement. Just use the conventional block div to fix the `Sidebar` and free flow the `.main-content`. Use grid inside these containers if you must.

Comment: Refer this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/44005710/3626796