# Using percentage padding trick to maintain aspect ratio causes overflow in CSS Grid

Tags: css, grid-layout, css-grid

I am using `padding-top` to force the aspect ratio of a div to 16:9. The contents of the div are positioned absolutely and expand to fill the div.

HTML:

```
<div class = "ratio-16-9">
  <p>This p element is in a div with an aspect ratio of 16:9.</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.ratio-16-9 {
  padding-top:56.25% /* Yields 16:9 aspect ratio. */;
  position:relative;
}

.ratio-16-9 > p {
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  top:0;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
```

It works nicely to achieve the aspect ratio, but the div is overflowing my CSS Grid container for some reason.

Here is a fiddle with the working example of the problem: https://jsfiddle.net/uo63yyer/30/

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

body {
  background-color: #404040;
  min-height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

p {
  color: #f0f0f0;
  text-align: center;
}

#content {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto;
  grid-template-rows: auto auto auto auto;
}

.topic {
  background-color: #808080;
  min-height: 100px;
  margin: 8px;
  padding: 8px;
}

.ratio-16-9 {
  background-color: #0080f0;
  padding-top: 56.25%;
  /* If you comment out the line above and uncomment the line below, things work propperly, but the aspect ratio is not maintained. */
  /*height:300px;*/
  position: relative;
}

.ratio-16-9>p {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">

  <div class="topic">
    <div class="ratio-16-9">
      <p>This p element is in a div with an aspect ratio of 16:9.</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="topic">
  </div>

  <div class="topic">
  </div>

  <div class="topic">
    <div>
      <!-- Uncomment the line below and things work propperly. -->
      <!--<p>This p element is in a propperly sized div and it works as one might expect it to.</p>-->
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem appears to be the use of `auto` to size the grid column:

```
#content {
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto;
  grid-template-rows: auto auto auto auto;
}
```

Percentage padding is calculated with respect to the **width** of the containing block ([spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/box.html#padding-properties)).

For whatever reason, the `auto` value is being ignored for this purpose by the browser.

If you switch from `auto` to `fr` units, the layout works as intended.

```
#content {
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-rows:auto auto auto auto;
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

body {
  background-color: #404040;
  min-height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

p {
  color: #f0f0f0;
  text-align: center;
}

#content {
  display: grid;
  /* grid-template-columns:auto; */
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: auto auto auto auto;
}

.topic {
  background-color: #808080;
  min-height: 100px;
  margin: 8px;
  padding: 8px;
}

.ratio-16-9 {
  background-color: #0080f0;
  padding-top: 56.25%;
  /* If you comment out the line above and uncomment the line below, things work propperly, but the aspect ratio is not maintained. */
  /*height:300px;*/
  position: relative;
}

.ratio-16-9>p {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <div class="topic">
    <div class="ratio-16-9">
      <p>This p element is in a div with an aspect ratio of 16:9.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="topic"></div>
  <div class="topic"></div>
  <div class="topic">
    <div>
      <!-- Uncomment the line below and things work propperly. -->
      <!--<p>This p element is in a propperly sized div and it works as one might expect it to.</p>-->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/uo63yyer/31/

---

Also, be aware that using percentage-based padding on grid items may render differently across browsers. [Percentage padding on grid item being ignored in Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42708323/3597276)

Comment: I never thought to look at the column sizing because it seemed like a height issue! Thank you! Since the % padding can be problematic, is there a better way to get CSS bases constant aspect ratios?

Comment: Well, percentage padding can be a problem on *grid items*. But your `.ration-16-9` element is not a grid item. It's a child of a grid item and, therefore, outside the scope of grid layout.

Comment: Ah, thank you for the clarification and new insight into my issue.

Comment: However, I posted the cautionary note at the end because I'm not sure how the browsers will compute width on grid items when calculating a descendant's percentage padding.

Comment: Both grid and flex items have the same issue with percentage padding. This flex post has some workaround suggestions. http://stackoverflow.com/q/36783190/3597276