# CSS grid-template-rows auto resetting scroll position to the bottom on hover

Tags: css, grid, overflow, css-grid

Is it expected behaviour that whenever you hover on whatever element in the section of the `grid-template-rows` that has `overflow` and `auto height` moves `scroll` position to the bottom of the overflown container (`body` in this case)?

**The most visible scroll breaking effect is when you are doing circles between 2 `li` elements and trying to scroll either up or down on snippet #1.**

When I remove `:hover` on `li` the scroll doesn't break.

```css
.container{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 10vh auto 8vh;
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
  background: rgba(0,0,0.2);
}

.header{
  background: lightblue;
}

.body{
  background: white;
  overflow: auto;
}

.footer{
  background: lightgreen;
}

li{
  height: 30px;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
  opacity: 1;
}
li:nth-child(even){
  background: rgba(0,0,0,.2);
}

li:hover{
  opacity: .1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="header">header</div>
  <div class="body">body
  <ul>
    <li>foo</li>
    <li>foo</li>
    <li>foo</li>
    <li>foo</li>
    <li>foo</li>
    <li>foo</li>
    <li>foo</li>
    <li>foo</li>
    <li>foo</li>
    <li>foo</li>
    <li>foo</li>
    <li>foo</li>
    <li>foo</li>
    <li>foo</li>
    <li>foo</li>
    <li>foo</li>
    <li>foo</li>
    <li>foo</li>
    <li>foo</li>
    <li>foo</li>
    <li>foo</li>
  </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="footer">footer</div>
</div>
```

On the other hand if you hardcode the middle value to be i.e `40vh` instead of `auto` scroll works as intended.

```css
.container{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 10vh 40vh 8vh;
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
  background: rgba(0,0,0.2);
}

.header{
  background: lightblue;
}

.body{
  background: white;
  overflow: auto;
}

.footer{
  background: lightgreen;
}

li{
  height: 30px;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
  opacity: 1;
}
li:nth-child(even){
  background: rgba(0,0,0,.2);
}

li:hover{
  opacity: .1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="header">header</div>
  <div class="body">body
  <ul>
    <li>foo</li>
    <li>foo</li>
    <li>foo</li>
    <li>foo</li>
    <li>foo</li>
    <li>foo</li>
    <li>foo</li>
    <li>foo</li>
    <li>foo</li>
    <li>foo</li>
    <li>foo</li>
    <li>foo</li>
    <li>foo</li>
    <li>foo</li>
    <li>foo</li>
    <li>foo</li>
    <li>foo</li>
    <li>foo</li>
    <li>foo</li>
    <li>foo</li>
    <li>foo</li>
  </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="footer">footer</div>
</div>
```

Comment: No breaking scroll for me, on Chrome

Comment: Both snippets? Or just second? Cus it breaks for me on latest Chrome / Opera updates (`58.0.30291`) though it works smoothly on Firefox

Comment: Both works the same for me...Chrome 58.0.3029.110 (64-bit) on Windows 10

Comment: Hmm, were you moving your mouse between 2 `li's` while trying to scroll? Because thats the moment when the scroll breaks

Comment: Okay, missed that small info....when move cursor in a circle in first sample, it does do that and no idea why

Comment: Can reproduce while circling and scrolling at the same time in the first example. Second is fine. 1fr: `grid-template-rows: 10vh 1fr 8vh;` is also fine but not auto… You may want to [report bug to Chrom(e|ium)](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/list). According to [spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-grid-1/#adapting-to-available-space), auto sizes the column to fit its content so maybe it can't due to height and overflow on parent and then I don't know :)

Comment: Seems like `fr` unit is a way to go then. Was thinking the same about `overflow` and `height` correlation which kinda makes sense, but then again, scroll doesn't break in Firefox so that could be chrome / webkit bug since the behaviour is the same in chrome is the same as in opera.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have noticed several odd behaviors in CSS Grid when using the `auto` value on `grid-template-*` properties ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44014004/3597276)). What has always worked for me is switching from `auto` to `1fr`.

Comment: Wow. This was a huge help, resolving with extreme simplicity an otherwise inscrutable problem. Who knows how long I might have spent trying to work around this bizarre, undocumented, de-scrolling when replacing "auto" with "1fr" made the problem disappear. Thanks a ton.